# How to display the json data in tree structure

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I have a json data which I want to display as a tree in a html page using AngularJS.
Also I want to make that tree dynamic so that later on, if I add more data in that json, I won't need to change any html code.

Here is my json:

```
{
"Customer1": {
    name: "Customer1"
    "CODEGROUP1": {
        "name": "Group1",
        "CODELIST":{
            "CODE18": {
                "name": "Test51",
                "codeId": "526"
            }
        }
    },
    "CODEGROUP2": {
        "name": "Group2",
        "CODEGROUP3": {
            "name": "Group3",
            "CODELIST": {
                "CODE19": {
                    "name": "Test52",
                    "codeId": "582"
                }
            }
        },
        "CODELIST": {
            "CODE20": {
                "name": "Test53",
                "codeId": "554"
            }
        }
    },
    "CODELIST": {
           "CODE21": {
                "name": "Test55",
                "codeId": "564"
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: A web search for "angular tree" would have provided you numerous results. Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service...especially when no effort is shown in question to resolve the issue at hand

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Jquery json viewer](https://github.com/abodelot/jquery.json-viewer) plugin to show json as tree ,

as below snippet :

```js
var data = {
  "data": "value",
  "data2": {
    "mounir": "mounir",
    "mounir2": {
      "city": "bRIMOs",
      "data3": "value3"
    }
  }
}

$(function(){
  $('#json-renderer').jsonViewer(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://rawgit.com/abodelot/jquery.json-viewer/master/json-viewer/jquery.json-viewer.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/abodelot/jquery.json-viewer/master/json-viewer/jquery.json-viewer.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<pre id="json-renderer"></pre>
```